# Can somebody clear these questions about infopath with sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I faced few more questions while interview. it was totally new for me. can you please help me out to clear more idea :

```
- What is infopath ( I can use MSDN)
- Can i Design InfoPath form in Sharepoint Designer 2010
- How to deploy Infopath form in Sharepoint site. (I can follow MSDN here)
- What authority needs to deploy Infopath in sp?
- What is Group and fields in infopath?
- Can I write custom event in InfoPath? What is VSTA? 
- How add rule in Infopath form
- How to validate Infopath fields?
- Can I show InfoPath in Webpart ?
- Where infopath will deploy?
- Can I show Infopath fields in List?
- Can I configure workflow with Infopath in SP?
- What are advantages and disadvantages of using Infopath? ( I can google it)
- How IIS works against the Infopath request ?
- How Sharepoint request handle by IIS?
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is rather broad. You may want to obtain a book about InfoPath or attend a training course.

Short answers in relation to SharePoint:

*- What is infopath ( I can use MSDN)*

InfoPath is a tool for designing and distributing structured XML data in user-friendly forms. It can use complex logic and processing rules. Some people call it an XML editor on steroids.

*- Can i Design InfoPath form in Sharepoint Designer 2010*

No. To edit/create InfoPath forms, you need InfoPath Designer. It comes in all flavours, from 2003 to 2013.

*- How to deploy Infopath form in Sharepoint site. (I can follow MSDN here)*

If you customize a SharePoint list form with InfoPath, just click the Publish button. If you create a Browser form, you can publish it to a Forms Library, either as a content type or an actual library item.

*- What authority needs to deploy Infopath in sp?*

That depends on the type of InfoPath form. An InfoPath form with code can be deployed by a Designer to the sandbox. Trusted forms with code may need to be deployed as administrator approved forms, via Central Administration. In most cases though, Designer permissions are sufficient, i.e. if you can create a new list or library, you can also create and deploy InfoPath Browser Forms or customise list forms with InfoPath.

*- What is Group and fields in infopath?*

InfoPath Browser forms offer Groups as a container for fields that belong together. How they "belong together" is completely in the hands of the designer and the business rules and logic that makes up the form. InfoPath list forms do not support groups.

*- Can I write custom event in InfoPath? ...*

InfoPath List Forms do not support any kind of code. InfoPath browser forms do support code.

*- ...What is VSTA?*

Is your Google broken?

*- How add rule in Infopath form*

Click a control, open the Rules panel (Home ribbon > Manage Rules), click New

*- How to validate Infopath fields?*

Create a validation rule.

*- Can I show InfoPath in Webpart ?*

Yes. You can use an InfoPath form web part for that. You can link it to either a Browser Form (that is stored in an InfoPath Forms library), or a list form of a list in the same site.

*- Where infopath will deploy?*

InfoPath forms can be stored in a SharePoint forms Library or directly in a SQL database. InfoPath list forms will always store their data in the corresponding SharePoint list. In a SharePoint context, the InfoPath form itself will be a Content Type in a Forms Library or the site collection, or the list form for a SharePoint list.

*- Can I show Infopath fields in List?*

InfoPath forms stored in a Library can be configured to expose selected fields as library columns. To extract the other fields, specific query tools are required (not part of SharePoint out of the box). InfoPath list forms store all their fields in the respective list.

*- Can I configure workflow with Infopath in SP?*

Yes. InfoPath can be used to create some rudimentary workflow steps, but not as sophisticated as SharePoint Designer or other 3rd party tools. InfoPath forms are very easy to integrate with SharePoint workflows, though.

*- What are advantages and disadvantages of using Infopath? ( I can google it)*

Well then, do that.

*- How IIS works against the Infopath request ?
 - How Sharepoint request handle by IIS?*

An InfoPath form is a bunch of XML data with some elaborate formatting, using its own flavour of XSLT and CSS. IIS is way down the food chain, as far as I know and will only handle what the SharePoint server passes to it.

A more detailed response to your multi-faceted question would basically be a book about InfoPath for Beginners. These books already exist and it's beyond the scope of a question to dump a whole book of learning into a reply. Your best approach for InfoPath is to try it out. Install InfoPath Designer 2010 and get going. It's not very hard to learn and actually can be quite fun, in a geeky way. InfoPath is VERY powerful and can do a lot of things with just a few clicks that are very, very hard to do with SharePoint Designer.

When it comes to list forms, many things that can be done with InfoPath can also be done with javascript, especially with tools like SPServices by Marc Anderson (on CodePlex). But InfoPath can do these things by clicking a few buttons, and not involving code.

A developer can take InfoPath to yet another level and create code to fill the functionality gaps that SharePoint has.

Hint: InfoPath as a tool is not really on topic for StackOverflow, unless you are dealing with coding challenges. Questions about specific InfoPath problems are more suited at http://Sharepoint.stackexchange.com